# savedInstanceState всегда null

Tags: java, android

savedInstanceState всегда со значением null, возможно не срабатывает onSaveInstanceState() 
Код:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Если операция уничтожается при нажатии пользователем кнопки Назад или
>   завершении операции, система считает, что экземпляр Activity исчезает
>   навсегда, так как такое поведение указывает, что операция больше не
>   нужна. Однако если система уничтожает операцию в связи с системными
>   ограничениями (а не в процессе обычной работы приложения), хотя
>   фактический Activity экземпляр исчезает, система помнит о его
>   существовании, и если пользователь вернется к нему, система создаст
>   новый экземпляр действия, используя набор сохраненных данных,
>   описывающий состояние операции на момент ее уничтожения. Сохраненные
>   данные, используемые системой для восстановления предыдущего
>   состояния, называются "состоянием экземпляра" и представляют собой
>   набор пар "ключ-значение", хранящийся в объекте Bundle.

Подробнее: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating?hl=RU

Answer (score -3):

**Для сохранения данных лучше использовать метод onPause() поскольку метод onSaveinstanceState() вызывается не во всех случаях**

Comment: onSaveinstanceState() вызываеться как раз перед onStop().